# jQuery mobile load another page to div

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to read the content of page B to page A.

The page A contains the Header, Content and Footer, and I only want to change the Content div.

So, in the page A, I have the following code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Website</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
        <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="mainpage">
            <div data-role="panel" id="leftPanel">
                <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="b" data-divider-theme="c">
                    <li><a href="#" id="services">Services</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
                <h1>News</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content" id="content">
                <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
                    <li>Testing A</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-fullscreen="true">
                <h1>Footer</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#services").click( function () {
            $('#content').load('services.php #contentindex');
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

And in the page B (which is services.php) I have:

```
<html><head>
    <body>
        <div id="contentindex">
            <ul>
                <li>Lets go people!</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</head>
</html>
```

So, I have a two questions:

1. It's possible to load the php page? I know its possible to load HTML (although I didn't accomplish that)
2. I'm not getting any errors but I dont get any content either
3. It's necessary load in the page B the stylesheets and scripts like the page A?

Thanks guys.

Comment: why not use php built in functions for this exact purpose. `require('services.php')`, `include('services.php')` or `require_once()` or `include_once()`

Comment: Hmm, I think you didn't get what I want. I'm trying to load the contents of another page without changing the page. 
I found that I can create multiple Pages in the same page..but it will not be organized :\